# Using Enzyme and Jest to find a className within a component

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, components, enzyme

I'm trying to perform a simple unit test to confirm that my `Register` component renders a `.container`. I believe it may be a level/hierarchy issue with `shallow`, or possibly a render issue but I can't be for sure.

The following is my `Register` component.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Link, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

//redux
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { setAlert } from '../../actions/alert';
import { register } from '../../actions/auth';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const Register = ({ setAlert, register, authState: { isAuthenticated } }) => {

  //...

  if (isAuthenticated) {
    return <Redirect to='/dashboard' />;
  }

  return (
    <section className='container'> <====== I want to verify this container so I can do further testing by calling find('input') on the container.
      <h1 className='large text-primary'>Sign up</h1>
      <p className='lead'>
        <i className='fas fa-user-circle'> Create Your Account</i>
      </p>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className='form'>
        <div className='form-group'>
          <input
            type='text'
            placeholder='Name'
            value={name}
            onChange={e => handleNameChange(e)}
            required
          />
        </div>
       //...
    </section>

Register.propTypes = {
  setAlert: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  register: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  authState: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  authState: state.auth 
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { setAlert, register })(Register);
```

This is my App component which shows my application's hierarchy:

```
const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (localStorage.token) {
      setAuthToken(localStorage.token);
      store.dispatch(loadUser());
    }
  }, []); 

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
        <Fragment>
          <Navbar />
          <Route exact path='/' component={Landing} />
          <section className='container'>
            <Alert />
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path='/Register' component={Register} />
              <Route exact path='/Login' component={Login} />
              //...
     </Provider>
   );

export default App;
```

The following is my test file, along with all my attempts of using `dive()` to be in the correct level or not, or using different Enzyme methods such as `find()`, `hasClass()`, etc.

I've tried explicitly passing the props required by the component during render, as well as passing them in as the initial state for my mock store.

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import toJson from 'enzyme-to-json';
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store'; 
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'; store

// Component to be tested
import Register from '../../../src/components/auth/Register';
// Props for the Register component
import { setAlert } from '../../../src/actions/alert';
import { register } from '../../../src/actions/auth';

// Mock Store
const mockStore = configureMockStore();
const store = mockStore({
  setAlert: setAlert,
  register: register,
  authState: {
    isAuthenticated: false,
    loading: false,
  },
});

describe('<Register /> component renders a <section> with className container.', () => {
  let props;

  beforeEach(() => {
    props = {
      setAlert: setAlert,
      register: register,
      authState: {
        token: localStorage.getItem('token'),
        isAuthenticated: false,
        loading: false,
        loggedInUser: null,
      },
    };
  });

  test("Attempt #1: No dive() and .find('section')", () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Register {...props} />
      </Provider>
    );
    const section = wrapper.find('section');
    expect(section.length).toBe(1); // Section.length returns 0
  });

  test("Attempt #2: Use dive() and .find('section')", () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Register {...props} />
      </Provider>
    ).dive();
    const section = wrapper.find('section');
    expect(section.length).toBe(1); // Section.length returns 0
  });

  test("Attempt #3: No dive() and .hasClass('container')", () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Register {...props} />
      </Provider>
    );
    expect(wrapper.hasClass('container')).toEqual(true); // hasClass returns false
  });

  test("Attempt #4: Use dive() and .hasClass('container')", () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Register {...props} />
      </Provider>
    ).dive();
    expect(wrapper.hasClass('container')).toEqual(true); // hasClass returns false
  });

  test('Attempt #5: No dive() and .to.have.lengthOf(1)', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Register {...props} />
      </Provider>
    );
    expect(wrapper.find('.container')).to.have.lengthOf(1); // Can't read property have of undefined
  });

  test('Attempt #6: Use dive() and .to.have.lengthOf(1)', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Register {...props} />
      </Provider>
    ).dive();
    expect(wrapper.find('.container')).to.have.lengthOf(1); // Can't read property of undefined
  });
});
```

The following are the output of wrapper.debug():

```
// The wrapper without dive()
<ContextProvider value={{ store: { getState: [Function: getState], getActions: [Function: getActions], dispatch: [Function: dispatch], clearActions: [Function: clearActions], subscribe: [Function: subscribe], replaceReducer: [Function: replaceReducer] }, subscription: { store: { getState: [Function: getState], getActions: [Function: getActions], dispatch: [Function: dispatch], clearActions: [Function: clearActions], subscribe: [Function: subscribe], replaceReducer: [Function: replaceReducer] }, parentSub: undefined, unsubscribe: null, listeners: { notify: [Function: notify] }, handleChangeWrapper: [Function: bound handleChangeWrapper], onStateChange: [Function: notifyNestedSubs] } }}>
      <Connect(Register) setAlert={[Function: setAlert]} register={[Function: register]} authState={{ token: null, isAuthenticated: false, loading: false, loggedInUser: null }} />
    </ContextProvider>
```

```
// The Wrapper using dive():
<Connect(Register) setAlert={[Function: setAlert]} register={[Function: register]} authState={{ token: null, isAuthenticated: false, loading: false, loggedInUser: null }} />
```

All my attempts either return 0 nodes, or returns false. Am I not looking in the correct level? Is each attempt failing from a potential missing prop requirement which fails an attempt to render the component?

The following is a link to my repo, under the branch `test-component-help`:

[My Repo](https://github.com/boxcarcoder/ExplorersConnect)

And the files in question's locations:

Test file: `./client/__tests__/components/auth/Register.test.js`

Component: `./client/src/components/auth/Register.js`

Comment: could you console.log your `isAuthenticated`? maybe control isn't reaching your render and returns at redirect.

Comment: I added `console.log(props.authState.isAuthenticated)` after my `shallow()` call, which output `false`. Was this the correct way to check the state of `isAuthenticated`?

Comment: You should add that log line in your component itself and not in test file. Just before your `if(isAuthenticated)` line.

Comment: I've added the `console.log` in my component but when I run my test file, there is no output. That leads me to believe the component is not being rendered. However, I check the length of `wrapper` after my `shallow` call, which returns 1. Does that mean the component is rendered? If so, why isn't the `console.log` executed?

Comment: probably you have --silent flag for your test script `test: jest --silent`? Try with a mount as well and log wrappers debug API output. If that doesn't help, put a link to your project on GitHub. Could have a look and contribute if I could.

Comment: When I try `mount`, there is an error with the `authState` prop required in my component. I've tried including the `authState` in the props when I render `Register` in my test file, and I've tried passing `authState` as an initialState to my mock store in my test file as well. My test script is only `"test": "jest --verbose --runInBand"`. I've put a link to my repo in my main post if you can take a look. The test file will be under `./client/__tests__/components/auth/Register.test.js`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the `.container` className within my Register component by separating the Redux logic aspect from the Component aspect. The Redux logic is tested in separate test files for actions, and test files for reducers, allowing me to test the render of the component without Redux logic.

In order to test the component without the Redux logic, I had to export a version of my component that isn't connected to a Redux store:

```
/// *** Export the non-connected version of the component for testing.
export const Register = ({ setAlert, register, authState: { isAuthenticated } }) => {
  //...

  if (isAuthenticated) {
    return <Redirect to='/dashboard' />;
  }

  return (
    <section className='container'> <====== I want to verify this container so I can do further testing by calling find('input') on the container.
      <h1 className='large text-primary'>Sign up</h1>
      <p className='lead'>
        <i className='fas fa-user-circle'> Create Your Account</i>
      </p>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className='form'>
        <div className='form-group'>
          <input
            type='text'
            placeholder='Name'
            value={name}
            onChange={e => handleNameChange(e)}
            required
          />
        </div>
       //...
    </section>

Register.propTypes = {
  setAlert: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  register: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  authState: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  authState: state.auth 
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { setAlert, register })(Register);
```

Now that I have a version of my component without Redux logic, I can import it and test it:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

// *** Import the non-connected component for testing.
import { Register } from '../../../src/components/auth/Register';

// Globals for test
let props;
let wrapper;
let mockSetAlert = jest.fn();
let mockRegister = jest.fn();

// *** No longer need to mock a store to connect to.

describe('<Register /> component.', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    props = {
      setAlert: mockSetAlert,
      register: mockRegister,
      authState: {
        isAuthenticated: false,
      },
    };

    // *** No longer need to use a Provider to connect the component to the Redux store
    wrapper = shallow(<Register {...props} />);
  });

  test('Renders a <section> with className container.', () => {
    const section = wrapper.find('section');
    expect(section.length).toBe(1); 
  });
```

Without the need to have a Provider that connects to the Redux store, the hierarchy is straightforward. Without a Redux store, there is also no confusion as to whether or not to pass the props through the store, or to pass the props directly during rendering.

Answer (score 0):

It probably related to the fact that you are rendering the component using `shallow`, which renders only the upper level component (without it's `children`) therefore, your inner child won't exist.

Change the `shallow` render to `mount` which renders the entire component.

A side tip, you can call `wrapper.debug()` to see the "html" of the rendered wrapper.

Comment: I wish to use shallow since it provides true unit testing, as opposed to mount which would render child components. Is there a way I can proceed with shallow? I've figured out how to get wrapper.debug() to work. I'll include the results in my main post.

Answer (score 0):

- Instead of passing `authState` to component as prop, you need to have correct mock store and it'd be sent as prop to your `Register` component. (instead of explicit prop as you're doing now).

> Update your mockStore as (or have a separate mock for this test in its scope):

```js
const store = mockStore({
authState: {
        isAuthenticated: true,
        loading: false,
      }
});
```

Then you can run your test with those 4 attempts you made. I think they'll pass.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion of passing in my authState into the mock store in various ways, all yielding the same results. With each attempt at mocking the store, I didn't explicitly pass the props when rendering. The results are the same as when I passed authState as a prop (the wrapper.debug() didn't change, and the tests still result in 0 nodes found). I've updated my original post to reflect my attempts of mocking the store.

Comment: I cloned your repo and tried running tests but it fails at finding some db keys, also there's no mention in your package about which node version to use. Couldn't do much.